# Sound playing through wrong output

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am currently using a dual monitor setup in my home studio but I have run into a small problem for which I do not know the solution.

I have a program open on my 1st monitor which then plays on the second monitor once I hit the play button. This is frustrating because I need to hear this audio through my studio speakers which can only be hooked up to the laptop and not the second screen which is where the sound is coming from. Any help on directing audio to the laptop instead of the second screen?

Comment: What operating system? What cable are you using to connect the second screen?

Comment: Windows 10 and im using the HDMI port on my laptop to hook it up to an hdtv

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is select your audio output. HDMI generally sets itself as the default audio device, but it is easy to change this.

The easiest thing to do is to **click** on the **volume control** in the **taskbar**. The title above the volume slider is actually a selection menu. **Click** on this and **choose** the output you prefer and your audio should start heading that way.

You can also **right-click** on the **volume control** and select **Playback Devices**, then set your preferred output as default in the **Sound** dialog.

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked for me was to quit the program which was using ASIO4All v2 – it seems like it was confusing Windows about available sound devices? As soon as I took the right device (a Bluetooth headset) from ASIO, the sound selector that [music2myear describes](https://superuser.com/q/1191992/150988#1192013):

> … **click** on the **volume control** in the **taskbar**. 
>   The title above the volume slider is actually a selection menu. 
>   **Click** on this and **choose** the output you prefer
>   and your audio should start heading that way.

started to kind-of work. (At first, selecting the computer speakers cause the sound to come out of the headset, but then selecting the headset worked as expected, and switching also worked.